# Laravel Cashier new subscription with Stripe throws "Could not determine which URL to request:" error

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, subscription, laravel-cashier

I'm using Laravel 6 and Cashier 10.7 to handle subscriptions on my platform. One off payments to Stripe are working fine and so is switching from one subscription to another, but when I try to initiate a new subscription for a customer with no stored card I get an error

> Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe\PaymentMethod
>   instance has invalid ID:

My payment form looks like this;

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 mt-5 mb-2">

            @if (session('status'))
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                    {{ session('status') }}
                </div>
            @endif

            @if ($errors->any())
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <strong>Whoops!</strong> There was a problem.
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif

            <div class="h2 text-center">
                {{ __('Please enter your card details') }}
            </div>

            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('startSubscription') }}" id="payment-form">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="group">
                            <label class="stripe-label">
                                <span class="mr-1 p-2">{{ __('Cardholder Name') }}</span>
                                <input id="card-holder-name" class="field" placeholder="Jordan Jones" />
                            </label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Stripe Elements Placeholder -->
                        <div class="group">
                          <label class="stripe-label">
                            <span class="mr-1 p-2">{{ __('Card') }}</span>
                            <div id="card-element" class="field p-3"></div>
                          </label>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Used to display form errors. -->
                        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                        <button id="card-button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success" data-secret="{{ $intent->client_secret }}">
                            <i class="fas fa-credit-card mr-1"></i>{{ __('Add Payment Method') }}
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('javascript')

<script>
    const stripe = Stripe('{{ env("STRIPE_KEY") }}');
    const elements = stripe.elements();
    const cardElement = elements.create('card', {hidePostalCode: true});

    cardElement.mount('#card-element');

    const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
    const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
    const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;

    cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
        const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(
            clientSecret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: cardElement,
                    billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                }
            }
        );

        if (error) {
            var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = error.message;
        } else {
          // Submit the form with the token ID.
           function stripePaymentHandler(setupIntent) {
           // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
           var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
           var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
           hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
           hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'payment_method');
           hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', setupIntent.payment_method);
           form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

           // Submit the form
           form.submit();
          }
        }
        });

</script>
@endsection
```

My controller like this;

```
public function subscriptionPayment(Request $request) {
  $user = Auth::user();
  $paymentMethod = $request->payment_method;

  try {
    if ($user->hasPaymentMethod()) {
      $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
    } else {
      $user->addPaymentMethod($paymentMethod);
    }

$newSubscription = $user->newSubscription('User', 'plan_HGvJkewD0eaY6G')->trialDays(60)->create($paymentMethod, ['email' => $user->email]);

  } catch ( IncompletePayment $exception ){
    return redirect()->route('payment',
                [$exception->payment->id, 'redirect' => route('home')]
    );
  }

  return redirect()->route('home')
    ->with('status', 'Your payment has been processed and your subscription is now active.');
  }
```

and the Stripe event log shows this;

> {   "object": {
>       "id": "seti_*******",
>       "object": "setup_intent",
>       "application": null,
>
> "cancellation_reason": null,
>     "client_secret": "seti_*********",
>     "created": 1591367952,
>     "customer": null,
>     "description": null,
>     "last_setup_error": null,
>     "livemode": false,
>     "mandate": null,
>       "metadata": {
>       },
>       "next_action": null,
>       "on_behalf_of": null,
>       "payment_method": null,
>       "payment_method_options": {
>         "card": {
>           "request_three_d_secure": "automatic"
>         }
>       },
>       "payment_method_types": [
>         "card"
>       ],
>       "single_use_mandate": null,
>       "status": "requires_payment_method",
>       "usage": "off_session"   } }

Can Anyone help with what I'm doing wrong, i just can't work it out.

Comment: Sounds like you are passing an invalid `id` string to $user->updateDefaultPaymentMethod($paymentMethod). It should be in the form of `pm_****` (or sometimes `card_****`). Might be the case that you're passing the entire `PaymentMethod` object instead of just the `id`.

Comment: Just var_dumped $paymentMethod and it's null.

Comment: It looks like maybe the form is submitting before the Stripe response with the paymentMethod, but shouldn't await command do this?

Comment: Tried hard coding hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', '1234'); into the js code, but var_dump on PaymentMethod is still coming back null. Looks like the js form append is not working, but I can't see why. Adding a simple hidden field to the form itself works.

Answer (score 1):

I tracked this down to 'defer' being present in the js script tag in the headers, which meant the event listeners weren't working and the form was submitting without waiting for the call and response from Stripe.
Fixed with a simple

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

after 2 days ‍♂️